# Comparison operators' priority in Python vs C/C++

Tags: python, comparison-operators

In C/C++, comparison operators such as `< >` have higher priority than `==` does. This code will evaluate to `true` or `1`:

```
if(3<4 == 2<3) {  //3<4 == 2<3 will evaluate to true
    ...
}
```

But in Python, it seems wrong:

```
3<4 == 2<3  #this will evaluate to False in Python.
```

In Python, does every comparison operator have the same priority?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python, not only do comparison operators gave the same priority, they are treated specially (they chain rather than group). From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#notin):

> Formally, if `a, b, c, ..., y, z` are expressions and `op1, op2, ..., opN` are comparison operators, then `a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z` is equivalent to `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... and y opN z`, except that each expression is evaluated at most once.

In your case, the expression

```
3<4 == 2<3
```

is equivalent to

```
3 < 4 and 4 == 2 and 2 < 3
```

which is `False` due to the second clause.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: yeah, all the comparisons have the same precedence

Long answer: you may want to have a look on the documentation: [Precedence on Python](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary)

Comment: @Alcott: one rule of thumb is that if you're at all tempted to use spacing to indicate the precedence, as you did in the C++ code above, then you should put the parentheses in. Otherwise your spacing could "lie".

Comment: @Alcott: as in any other languages, you want to put parentheses wherever you know the precedence rules are going to play against you, but ALSO when you feel it will be easier to understand the logic. I mean, `a < b and b > c` is going to work as expected (`and` has lower precedence than comparators, meaning `a < b` and `b > c` will be evaluated first), but there's nothing wrong with just making it explicit and helping anyone reading the code (eg. you!) in the way, specially when the code is more complex than that.