# Evaluation of comparison operators in Python behaving unexpectedly

Tags: python, operator-precedence

I'm TAing an introductory course on Python this semester (using 3.4) and recently came across an exercise about operator precedence and using parentheses to make a statement evaluate to true.

The exact question is:

```
Add a single pair of parentheses to the expression so that it evaluates to true.
1 < -1 == 3 > 4
```

I assumed that the correct answer would be:

```
1 < -1 == (3 > 4)
```

Given that the comparison operators are all on the same level of precedence, they should evaluate from left to right, so it should evaluate as such:

```
1 < -1 == (3 > 4) 
1 < -1 == False
False == False
True
```

But when I run the code it still returns false. I saw this question [comparison operators' priority in Python vs C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802864/comparison-operators-priority-in-python-vs-c-c) and the result of that expression makes sense to me; but in this case I've forced the evaluation of the latter statement before evaluating the rest of the expression, so I don't get why I'm still getting the wrong answer.

I've been staring at it for the past hour and I feel like I might be overlooking something obvious; if anyone could provide some insight as to what the correct solution might be it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you understand the part of that answer about comparison *chaining*?  That answer explains how sequences of comparison operators do not operate according to a simple "precedence order" but are chained into multiple comparisons with `and`.

Comment: @BrenBarn I thought I understood it, but I guess I'm not getting the full implications. I'll try writing it out with the chaining and see if I can get a better idea of where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @BrenBarn Okay, so the actual statement being evaluated is 1 < -1 and -1 == (3 > 4) which results in a final evaluation of False and False, which results in False. I'll need to play around with it some more I guess. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @TerryChern: at the risk of giving out a spoiler, I'm not convinced that whoever wrote that puzzle wasn't also confused about comparison chaining in Python.. (or that there isn't a typo, and the last `>` is supposed to be `<`..)

Comment: @DSM Yeah, I'm looking at the assignment sheet supplied by my uni and they note for that specific problem that we "may use two pairs of parentheses."

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's a way to solve that particular one with only one set of parentheses.

Comment: I used a loop and `eval` to manually insert parentheses in every possible location to see if I was missing something, and found no solutions for `1 < -1 == 3 > 4`, although `1 < -1 == 3 < 4` had `(1 < -1 == 3) < 4`.

Comment: Well if anything this will be an interesting point to bring up in class with the students!

Comment: @BrenBarn If you'd like to submit an answer I'd be glad to accept it as the correct one (pointing to the chaining) otherwise I'll go ahead and accept Imran's as that's the conclusion I arrived at. Upvotes all around though for the help!

Comment: @DSM, did your loop evaluate `1 < -(1 == 3 > 4)`? Mine didn't, but it doesn't matter -- that's also `False`.

Comment: @Robᵩ: yep, because I was just inserting into all string positions and then catching the TypeErrors and SyntaxErrors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task is provably impossible. Consider these three cases:

1. There is an open paren immediately before `-1`.
2. There is an open paren between `-` and `1`.
3. There is an open paren anywhere else.

These three cases represent every possible location for the parentheses.

In the first case, we have `1 < ( ... )`, where the ellipsis is a boolean expression. Since `1` is not less than either `True` or `False`, the entire expression is `False`.

In the second case, we have `1 < -( ...)`, where the ellipsis is a boolean expression. Since `1` is not less than either `-True` nor `-False`, the entire expression is `False`.

In the third case, we have `1 < -1 == ...`. Since all legs of a expression of chained operators must be True, and and since `1 < -1` is False, the entire expression is `False`.

So, in every possible case, the result is False.

Comment: This is a great way to approach it; much better than manually adding the parentheses and checking each solution (although DSM did the much smarter method of automating it). Accepting this as the correct answer as it directly answers my question.

Comment: To be fair, you didn't actually ask a question, so it's difficult to say who answered it and who didn't.

Comment: Well, at the end I asked what's the correct answer and the correct answer is that there isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but due to comparison chaining you will have:

```
1 < -1 == (3 > 4) 
1 < -1 == False
1 < -1 and -1 == False
False and False
False
```

Notice that we don't evaluate the second line left to right, rather we chain the two comparisons together with an and.

There are only a few valid ways to add one pair of parentheses to this, so we can check all the others easily:

```
(1 < -1 == 3 > 4)
False #Trivially

(1 < -1) == 3 > 4
False == 3 > 4
False == 3 and 3 > 4
False and False
False

1 < (-1 == 3) > 4
1 < False > 4
1 < False and False > 4
False and False
False
```

It looks like there is no answer to this problem!

Edit:

Whoops! Rob points out we forgot:

```
1 < -(1 == 3) > 4
1 < -False > 4
1 < 0 > 4
1 < 0 and 0 > 4
False and False
False
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the conclusion I arrived at after reading BrenBarn's comment; I'll need to keep working at it I guess.

Comment: OK, I see you guys came to the same conclusion!

Comment: You skipped `1 < -(1 == 3) > 4` in your analysis.

Comment: If I could accept multiple correct answers I'd select this one as well; this is pretty much the process I went through to figure out that there were no working solutions. The implications of chaining were not fully clear to me at the time. I really appreciate the help, but Robᵩ's answer is much more rigorous.

Answer (score 1):

`3>4` gives `False`.
`-1 == False` gives `False`.
`1 < False` gives `False`.
Hence,
`1 < -1 == 3 > 4` becomes `False`.

Give proper brackets to make the statement semantically correct.

```
(1 < -1) == (3 > 4)
```

Comment: That's a solution that I was looking at but the idea is to only use a single pair of parentheses. I don't know if the textbook simply has it wrong though.

Comment: @TerryChern My guess is that the textbook was written for another language and converted to python (or, at least, the author was more familiar with something like C).  Python's behaviour in chained comparisons is very unusual (and only sporadically useful).

Answer (score 0):

(1 < -1) == (3 > 4)

False == False

True

Comment: Do note that the OP do not want an answer to solve the problem but an explanation of why his answer produce unexpected results.

Comment: Because he forgot parentheses on the left side of the expression:

`1 < -1 == (3 > 4)`

`1 < -1 == (false)`

`1 < -1 and -1 == (false)`

`false and false`

`false` Imran gave a correct explanation on the first part of its answer.